# C - scanf execute before print

Tags: c, eclipse

I try to run this code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   char str1[20], str2[30];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", str1);
   getc(stdin);

   printf("Enter your website name: ");
   scanf("%s", str2);
   getc(stdin);

   printf("Entered Name: %s\n", str1);
   printf("Entered Website:%s", str2);

   return(0);
}
```

from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

so I expected to get this in the console:

```
Enter name: admin
Enter your website name: admin.com

Entered Name: admin
Entered Website: admin.com
```

but actually I got this in my console:

```
admin
admin.com
Enter name: Enter your website name: Entered Name: admin
Entered Website:admin.com
```

so I would like to know why the scanf executed before the print.
maybe its related to using eclipse as IDE?

Comment: You might need to flush the stdout. printf will flush the stream on encountering '\n'.

Comment: Try to run the program from a terminal, it should be fine.

Comment: It's working as intended in `gcc` compiler. Issue must be with your IDE.

Comment: how can I flush? I try to add '\n' on the printf and scanf but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` between your printf and scanf.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compiler issue - ive only ever happen in eclipse. This is because it is trying to replicate unix compilation and therefor has some weird quirks

after every time you want to see output, place
fflush(stdout);

Comment: Looks like this answer has already been answered. If you have something to add to that, edit your post accodingly.